# What type of paper is this and how should I input it into JabRef?

Tags: publications, citations, authorship

As a follow up to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/139733/how-to-manage-publications-on-a-local-computer) I am now trying to use JabRef along with @Jonas Steins [python script](https://github.com/jonasstein/pybibtexcleaner) to manage a small literature database on my local machine. I came across the following conference paper :

http://epubs.surrey.ac.uk/852068/1/098_Argyroudis.et.al._rev.pdf

I tried adding it as "Proceedings" in JabRef but the only required fields which need to be added are:

- Title
- Year
- Bibtexkey

I find it really strange that entries which are conference proceedings do not require anything about the name of the conference, or the authors responsible for this particular article.

Am I looking at the wrong category? If so which one should I be looking at? Here are the possibilities in JabRef:

- Article
- InBook
- Book
- Booklet
- InCollection
- Conference
- InProceedings
- Proceedings
- Manual
- MastersThesis
- PhdThesis
- TechReport
- Unpublished
- Misc

If this *is* the right category, could someone please explain why the name of the conference and the authors are not required for this literature type?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a conference paper to me, so "InProceedings" is appropriate.

The one you thought of, "Proceedings" is for the entire conference.  i.e. the book that contains every single paper from the conference, not just a single paper. That's why there is no author field, and the title field is for the name of the conference.

BTW, definition of the categories is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX

Comment: "InProceedings" does not require you to insert the name of the conference anywhere.  I only see a "Booktitle" field which does not make sense to me. This is definitely not part of a book?

Comment: Booktitle *is* where you write the name of the conference. Or rather, it's for the title of the conference proceedings, which usually includes the name of the conference. When in doubt, just use "Proceedings of XY".

Comment: @user32882 Nowadays a lot of conference papers are only published electronically, but many still get printed in a single book (aka the "Proceedings") - that's why the field is called a "booktitle". (Plus the authors of BibTeX probably wanted to be consistent and not use too many different names for similar things.)

Comment: Allright then.... I wish they could have used something more descriptive than "BookTitle" but I realize I also need to learn more about these types of conventions. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

"Proceedings" refers to the entire conference proceedings as a single publication - e.g. *"Proceedings of the 2nd International Conference on Natural Hazards & Infrastructure"*.

What you are looking for is "InProceedings" - a single paper within the conference proceedings.

---

Besides these two, there is also "Conference". This is the same thing as "InProceedings", and exists purely for compatibility reasons.